# Is there any way to get a dark theme in Anypoint Studio?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

My eyeballs are bleeding from the brightness. Is there any way to get a dark theme in Anypoint Studio that doesn't look bad or require hours of configuration? I know about the dark theme in the preferences, but it screws up the colors in the editor so it's unusable. I'm in Anypoint 5.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anypoint Studio 7.9 enables users to use a dark theme:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.9-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes

Answer (score 4):

My Feature Request was finally approved and progressed, you can now use the dark theme here :) https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.9-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes

Find it here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.9-with-4.3-runtime-release-notes

ARCHIVE: The easiest way is: Preferences - General - Appearance and selecting the Dark option. But it does have visual bugs. You could apply some extra configurations to that Theme to make it more usable, but you will still have the visual bugs inside the components like HTTP Listeners.

We could start a voting for this "Idea" so Mulesoft will consider a Dark theme release.
https://support.mulesoft.com/s/ideas#087340000005w1fAAA

Answer (score 3):

I have Anypoint Studio 5.4.1.

Go to Window > Preferences > General > Appearance, then choose the Dark theme from the Theme drop down:

[Anypoint Studio Themes screenclip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwOpm.png)

Comment: Thanks but I know about that option, if you try it you'll see it messes with the colors in the editor and makes that part of the program unusable. I'm looking for themes that have been tested in Anypoint, that one looks like it's only skinning Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

To install a new Anypoint Studio Theme, navigate to the Help menu in Studio, then select Install New Software. Use the drop-down to select Anypoint Studio Themes, then browse the dozens of available themes. Follow the steps to download, then relaunch Studio with your new theme.

Comment: I don't see Anypoint Studio themes in the drop down, is there a site to add?

Answer (score 1):

You can install dark  theme from Help-->Install New Software

Comment: Should have clarified that I'm in 5.4.3, and there's no themes option in the software sources. Do they work in this version?

Comment: Don't see any themes there. Is there a repo?

Answer (score 0):

In Anypoint Studio 7.x.x, select from toolbar window-> preferences and then navigate to theme as shown in the image below.

[image]